# 'Data truncated for column 'in_operation' at row 1' issue with MySQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have been struggling with some strange issue with some MySQL stored precedure.

Here is the definition:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `search_audit`(
IN in_audit_search_type ENUM('USER','IP','HOSTNAME', 'SHARE', 'OPERATION', 'SOURCE', 'DESTINATION', 'ALL'),
IN in_user_name VARCHAR(32),
IN in_client_ip VARCHAR(15),
IN in_host_name VARCHAR(32),
IN in_share_name VARCHAR(32),
IN in_operation VARCHAR(24),
IN in_affected_item VARCHAR(8192),
IN in_new_name VARCHAR(8192),
IN in_start_date DATETIME,
IN in_end_date DATETIME)
BEGIN

    CASE in_audit_search_type
    
        WHEN 'USER'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                user_name = in_user_name AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'IP'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                client_ip = in_client_ip AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'HOSTNAME'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                host_name = in_host_name AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'SHARE'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                share_name = in_share_name AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'OPERATION'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                operation = in_operation AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'SOURCE'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                affected_item = in_affected_item AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        WHEN 'TARGET'
        THEN
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                operation,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                new_name = in_target AND
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;

        ELSE
            SELECT
                log_time,
                user_name,
                client_ip,
                host_name,
                share_name,
                `operation`,
                affected_item,
                new_name
            FROM
                audit
            WHERE
                log_time BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date;   

    END CASE;

END
```

I am trying to call this sproc from some C# app I have been trying to write. This is the definition for the C# sproc object:

```
            SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND = new MySqlCommand();
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Connection = DB_CONNECTION;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.CommandText = "search_audit";
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.CommandTimeout = 300;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_audit_search_type", MySqlDbType.Enum);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_user_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_client_ip", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_host_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_share_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_operation", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_affected_item", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_new_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_start_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_end_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
```

And this is my method that retrieves records:

```
        internal BindingList<AuditRecord> SearchAuditRecords(
        AuditSearchType searchType,
        string inUserName,
        string inClientIP,
        string inHostName,
        string inShareName,
        string inOperation,
        string inAffectedItem,
        string inNewName,
        DateTime startDate,
        DateTime endDate)
    {

        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_audit_search_type"].Value = searchType.ToString();
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_user_name"].Value = inUserName;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_client_ip"].Value = inClientIP;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_host_name"].Value = inHostName;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_share_name"].Value = inShareName;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_operation"].Value = inOperation;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_affected_item"].Value = inAffectedItem;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_new_name"].Value = inNewName;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_start_date"].Value = startDate;
        SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_end_date"].Value = endDate;


        DB_CONNECTION.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.ExecuteReader();

        BindingList<AuditRecord> records = new BindingList<AuditRecord>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            DateTime logDate = reader.GetDateTime(0);
            string userName = reader.GetString(1);
            string clientIP = reader.GetString(2);
            string hostName = reader.GetString(3);
            string shareName = reader.GetString(4);
            string operation = reader.GetString(5);
            string affectedItem = reader.GetString(6);
            string newName = reader.GetString(7);

            AuditRecord temp = new AuditRecord(logDate,userName, clientIP, hostName, shareName, operation, affectedItem, newName);
            records.Add(temp);
        }

        DB_CONNECTION.Close();

        return records;
    }
```

When I call this method, I get this exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Data truncated for column 'in_operation' at row 1'
```

But if I remove this line, it works:

```
SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_operation"].Value = inOperation;
```

It also works if I edit that line like this:

```
SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters["@in_operation"].Value = null;
```

This is the "audit" table creation statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE `audit` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affected_item` varchar(8192) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_name` varchar(8192) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `USER` (`user_name`,`share_name`,`operation`),
  KEY `SHARE` (`share_name`,`user_name`,`operation`),
  KEY `OPERATION` (`operation`,`user_name`,`share_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have been banging my head trying to understand why the exception is thrown. I have scoured the Internet for an answer. I am considering suicide at this point.

Comment: Does this `SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_operation", MySqlDbType.Text);` need to be VarChar instead of Text?

Comment: I forgot to mention that. MySqlDbType.VarChar does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truncate happens because in the procedure you declared `in_operation` as `VARCHAR(24)` but the `operation` column in the create table statement is `VARCHAR(32)`. To fix this change replace `VARCHAR(24)` to `VARCHAR(32)` in the procedure declaration:

```
{...}
IN in_operation VARCHAR(32),
{...}
```

Comment: No luck. Why do the other "VarChar"s work but this one does not? The problem is not the table's structure, that's for sure.

Comment: You need to provide what is stored in the database, my answer is assuming that the data stored size is bigger than what a `Varchar(32)` can handle. The other one might work because it is not bigger than a `Varchar(32)` can handle. Have you tried changing `IN in_operation VARCHAR(32)` to `IN in_operation TEXT`, and  `SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_operation", MySqlDbType.VarChar);` to `SEARCH_AUDIT_COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@in_operation", MySqlDbType.Text);`? Does it works with TEXT?

Comment: The sproc does not write anything to the database, it only reads. I have tried altering the table many times, even removing and recreating it. I have edited the question to reveal the whole sproc.

Comment: Do you have the `audit` table definition? Could you share it? I know you are only reading but you declared a Procedure and defined a `Varchar(24)`. Let's say for instance that the table `audit` has a `in_operation` string stored with 25 chars or more, this will generate the error on your code because you declared a `VARCHAR(24)` in the procedure but the string is bigger than that.

Comment: I just added the audit table creating statement. NB: The problem persists even when both the corresponding field and the sproc parameter are declared the same.

Comment: There you are, note that in your procedure you declared `VARCHAR(24)` and in the table create statement  `operation` is `varchar(32)`. Change the `VARCHAR(24)` to `VARCHAR(32)` in the procedure. Let me know if this works

Comment: Both were VarChar(32). Both are VarChar(32) now. Still, I get the same exception.

Comment: This is from your post :
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `search_audit`(
IN in_audit_search_type ENUM('USER','IP','HOSTNAME', 'SHARE', 'OPERATION', 'SOURCE', 'DESTINATION', 'ALL'),
{...}
IN in_operation VARCHAR(24),`
{...}
If you say you changed this to VARCHAR(32) and it still did not work I can't help you because it is supposed to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228019/discussion-between-scilek-and-francisco-de-castro).